# Curl Operation timed out with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I would like to get the content of a website using curl which is behind Cloudflare's service. The following code works fine most of the websites, but not which are behind Cloudflare and it fails even on cloudflare.com. Could you help me out what could cause such behavior?

I have the following configuration:

- PHP Version 5.6.31
- Curl: 7.54.0

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloudflare.com"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

// $output contains the output string 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

if ($result === FALSE) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
           htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}

fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

Result is:

```
cUrl error (#28): Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Error log:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://cloudflare.com/
*   Trying 198.41.214.162...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to cloudflare.com (198.41.214.162) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe it's a network issue for you.

Comment: It works for me too on a different server. This is why I'm not sure where to go next...

Comment: Anytime you rely on some external resource, it never fails that it will go down, not be available, etc, etc. You just have to plan for it, and come up with a solution that accommodates down time of external resources.

Comment: But this is not that case. Cloudflare.com is not down and I was never been able to get real response on this server from cloudflare.com. It is something with the connection... But I'm not sure where to look for clues.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess, and that it's a certificate problem. I know you've got verify peer and host set to false, but maybe cloudflare is blocking you because you have a self signed cert or something? Maybe? It's just the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: But when I connect cloudflare.com, I do not need any cert. They should have the SSL certification which I'm sure they have :) Also I tried it with SSL verify on and custom cacert.pem without luck.

Comment: Pretty sure that is Cloudflare’s DDoS protection at work here ... Sometimes when you visit a CF-hosted site in your browser, there is a small page from CF shown first, that says it is “checking your browser” or sth. like that. At least you should send a User-Agent matching a current browser.

Comment: It's not DDOS protection. I tried it on my own cloudflared site where I whitelisted the ip address of the server.